# int obj=new someMethod(); valid or not statement

Tags: java

Is this statement valid or not?

```
int obj=new someMethod();
```

Also I want to know that what difference it creates when we create a object with different reference and constructor, like this:

```
Object obj=new otherObject();
```

I mean how it is different from

```
Object obj=new Object();
```

'someMethod' is constructor of another class 'someMethod' and 'otherObject' is also constructor of class 'otherObject'. Object is a class.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is `someMethod`? What is `otherObject`? Also, when you were typing your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right. Worth a read.

Comment: Read "Head First Core Java" as soon as possbile.. worth to read it for basics to remember long time.

Comment: What's the difference between building a table and building a house? In the end, you get a table in the first case, and a house in the second case. Same with constructors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I will keep that in mind.actually I am new to stackoverflow.com .

Comment: 'someMethod' is constructor of another class 'someMethod' and 'otherObject' is also constructor of class 'otherObject'. Object is a class.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the wild guess that `someMethod` is a method of a class, e.g.:

```
int someMethod() {
    // Code here
}
```

...and that `otherObject` is an instance of a class, then no, neither of those statements is valid.

In Java, the `new` keyword is use to create an instance of a class. Classes are not methods, and are not objects.

The statement:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

is valid, and works, because `Object` is a class.

Now, of course, if `otherObject` is a *class*:

```
class otherObject {
    // Methods and such here
}
```

...then `Object obj = new otherObject();` is a valid statement, because all classes derive from `Object`, so it's okay to assign an `otherObject` instance to a variable declared as `Object`. Note that in Java, the *overwhelming* convention is to use initially-capped CamelCase for class names (so, `OtherObject` rather than `otherObject`).

I recommend stepping back and reading some decent Java introductory tutorials, which will explain classes, instances, methods, and such.

Comment: Well yes its a mistake but by someMethod() I meant its a constructor of class someMethod.and my second part of the query was not the validity of the statement.rather it was what's the difference between them...

Answer (score 1):

int obj=new someMethod(); is not valid. int is a data type, not a class. You cannot inherit from int so someMethod could never be an int class/object.

If someMethod is a method (as the name suggests :) you can have

```
int intObj = someMethod();
```

if someMethod returns and int like so:

```
int someMethod()
{
    return 5;
}
```

baseObject obj=new otherObject(); means that the class 'otherObject' inherits from 'baseObject'. For instance, if you have an Animal class then a class such as Dog can inherit from it so you can have

```
Animal spot = new Dog();
```

But you cannot have

```
Dog spot = new Animal();
```

Here's a link explaining java inheritance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Since all classes inherit from Object, Object obj = new OtherObject(); is valid

Answer (score 0):

```
int obj=new someMethod();
```

is not valid because when you create an object of any class you can not assign it basic data type.

```
Object obj=new otherObject();
```

is valid because an object of a class can be assign to its own type or to its **super class** and `Object` class is super class of all.